# Why CglibAopProxy use WeakHashMap as a synchronized lock?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-aop

`spring-aop 6.0.2`

I'm confused by the following CglibAopProxy class code:

```java
private static final Map<Class<?>, Boolean> validatedClasses = new WeakHashMap<>();

// ...

private void validateClassIfNecessary(Class<?> proxySuperClass, @Nullable ClassLoader proxyClassLoader) {
    if (!this.advised.isOptimize() && logger.isInfoEnabled()) {

        // Why is 'validatedClasses' a WeakHashMap?

        synchronized (validatedClasses) {
            if (!validatedClasses.containsKey(proxySuperClass)) {
                doValidateClass(proxySuperClass, proxyClassLoader,
                        ClassUtils.getAllInterfacesForClassAsSet(proxySuperClass));
                validatedClasses.put(proxySuperClass, Boolean.TRUE);
            }
        }
    }
}

// ...
```

I tried searching the Internet for related articles, but nothing solved my confusion.

Comment: Please learn [how to ask a question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Thank you.

Answer (score -2):

Your question is interesting, but hardly a good fit for Stack Overflow. This is a place to ask about your own programming problems, not one to inquire and speculate about the motives of third-party developers' design decisions.

Having said that, I am still in the holiday season spirit for now, trying to throw in a few thoughts:

- A weak hash map is useful when creating a cache in which, if no (strong) reference to the key exists anymore, the map entry (key and value) can be removed. I.e., a garbage collection can reclaim the memory for both the key and and the (often big and expensive) value. See [this tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/java-weakhashmap) for a comprehensive explanation with examples.
- You want to synchronise on objects or data structures which are not inherently thread-safe. In this case, it looks as if the developer wants to avoid the same class from being validated concurrently, before adding it to the cache.

Please avoid asking lots of follow-up questions, because SO is not a discussion forum. Maybe you better approach the Spring AOP team with such questions.

BTW, here is a [perma-link to the section of code in question](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/b71db12c43a1a09fa2fb49bf88ce8f00e017511b/spring-aop/src/main/java/org/springframework/aop/framework/CglibAopProxy.java#L251-L261), and here is one to the [Git blame/annotate version](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blame/b71db12c43a1a09fa2fb49bf88ce8f00e017511b/spring-aop/src/main/java/org/springframework/aop/framework/CglibAopProxy.java#L251), in which you can see that the `synchronized` section is 14 years old. The same is true for the weak hash map usage, if you follow  the merely structural changes in the code back to the original implementation.